# apply-templates not processed child nodes in order of select attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to format the number and rearrange the child nodes about the same format.

This is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<include>
    ...
    <data>
        <id>10001</id>
        <name>Archery classroom</name>
        <level>0</level>
        <description_5>Primary archery class.</description_5>
        <maxLevel>8</maxLevel>
        <skillRank>1</skillRank>
        <coolDownTime>6000</coolDownTime>
        <needMoney>5980</needMoney>
        <needSkillPoint>2</needSkillPoint>
        <skillUnitDataID>10001</skillUnitDataID>
        <icon>28</icon>
        <description_2>3</description_2>
        <coolDownID>10001</coolDownID>
    </data>
    <data>
        <id>10002</id>
        <name>Archery classroom</name>
        <level>1</level>
        <maxLevel>8</maxLevel>
        <skillRank>1</skillRank>
        <coolDownID>10002</coolDownID>
        <skillUnitDataID>10002</skillUnitDataID>
        <needMoney>15980</needMoney>
        <needSkillPoint>2</needSkillPoint>
        <coolDownTime>16000</coolDownTime>
        <icon>28</icon>
        <description_2>3</description_2>
        <description_3>11</description_3>
        <description_5>Primary archery class.</description_5>
    </data>
    ...
</include>
```

I want to separate the group for thousands for `coolDownTime` and rearrange the child nodes according to the same order: `id` -> `name` -> `level` -> `maxLevel` -> `skillRank` -> `needMoney` -> `needSkillPoint` -> `coolDownID` -> `coolDownTime` -> `skillUnitDataID` -> `description_1` -> `description_2` -> `description_3` -> `description_4` -> `description_5` -> `icon`.

This is the XSL code I used to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="id|name|level|maxLevel|skillRank|needMoney|needSkillPoint|coolDownID"/>
            <coolDownTime>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(coolDownTime,'#,000.#######')"/>
            </coolDownTime>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="skillUnitDataID|description_1|description_2|description_3|description_4|description_5|icon"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the results I received only `coolDownTime` were formatted group separation for thousands, the child nodes didn't arrange in the order that I was predetermined.

It seems that the code I wrote wasn't exactly somewhere.

So I'm very pleased with the suggestions you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "comma operator" `,` to select items in a certain order (e.g. `id, name, level`), not the union operators `|` which forms sequences of nodes sorted in document order.

Comment: This answer assumes XSLT 2.0+. If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, you'll need a sequence of separate `xsl:apply-templates` instructions, one for each element.

Comment: @MichaelKay, yes, but the original code had `version="2.0"`.

Comment: Yes, but other people coming along later and reading the answer might not spot that. And in any case, people throw 1.0 code labelled with version="2.0" at 1.0 processors all the time, and it works so they don't notice.

Comment: Well, it's true that I have misused the operator here. Surprisingly, some of the code I wrote before using the union operators here but it still works properly.
@MichaelKay Yes, I tried to lower the version to 1.0, it still works.